# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid size

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jpanel

I'm working on a school project in Netbeans.
Tried to build a simple GUI panel and frame with some options to draw a few objects. I started to add some new text fields and a button to let the user draw an object with some input like hight, width and quantity.

After this the program would not run anymore, it throws an exception which looks like an Illegal argument of some kind? 
This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid size
at javax.swing.GroupLayout.checkResizeType(GroupLayout.java:354)
at javax.swing.GroupLayout.checkSize(GroupLayout.java:339)
at javax.swing.GroupLayout.access$500(GroupLayout.java:208)
at javax.swing.GroupLayout$GapSpring.<init>(GroupLayout.java:3173)
at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Group.addGap(GroupLayout.java:1550)
at 
javax.swing.GroupLayout$SequentialGroup.addGap(GroupLayout.java:1855)
at ProjectPanel.initComponents(ProjectPanel.java:322)
at ProjectPanel.<init>(ProjectPanel.java:26)
at ProjectFrame.<init>(ProjectFrame.java:18)
at ProjectFrame$1.run(ProjectFrame.java:78)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
atjava.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
BUILD STOPPED (total time: 9 seconds)
```

I tried to debug and see where this error is created but I can't seem to find a specific line.

I'm sorry to post this complete code but I can't seem to find another option to get this back running..

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ProjectPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {
private int kind = 0;
private int strandstoel;
private String vliegerKleur = "Groen";
private int aantal, hoogte, breedte;

public ProjectPanel() {
    initComponents();
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    //Strand
    Color myBeach = new Color(240, 230, 140);
    g.setColor(myBeach);
    g.fillRect(0, 600, 1500, 400);

    //Sky
    Color mySky = new Color(245, 255, 250);
    g.setColor(mySky);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 1500, 600);

    //SunShine
    if (jCheckBoxZon.isSelected()) {
        Color sunShine = new Color(255, 215, 0);
        g.setColor(sunShine);
        g.fillOval(500, 150, 200, 200);

    } else {
        // REGEN + DONKERE LUCHT
        Color darkSky = new Color(128, 128, 128);
        g.setColor(darkSky);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 1500, 600);

        Color rain = new Color(30, 144, 255);
        g.setColor(rain);
        g.drawLine(100, 50, 100, 200);
        g.drawLine(200, 50, 200, 1);
        g.drawLine(300, 50, 300, 100);
        g.drawLine(400, 50, 400, 1);
        g.drawLine(500, 50, 500, 100);
        g.drawLine(600, 50, 600, 1);
        g.drawLine(700, 50, 700, 150);
        g.drawLine(800, 50, 800, 1);
        g.drawLine(850, 50, 850, 200);
        g.drawLine(900, 50, 900, 150);
        g.drawLine(1000, 50, 1000, 1);
        g.drawLine(1100, 50, 1100, 100);
        g.drawLine(1150, 50, 1150, 200);
        g.drawLine(1200, 50, 1200, 1);
        g.drawLine(1300, 50, 1300, 150);
        g.drawLine(1400, 50, 1400, 1);
        g.drawLine(1500, 50, 1500, 100);
    }

    //Zee
    Color seaShore = new Color(0, 191, 255);
    g.setColor(seaShore);
    g.fillRect(0, 400, 1500, 200);

    //Kite
    Color flyKite = new Color(0, 255, 127);
    g.setColor(flyKite);
    g.fillPolygon(new int[]{100, 300, 350}, new int[]{100, 300, 65}, 
3);

    // Kinderen
    int x1 = 125;
    int x2 = 150;
    int x3 = 130;
    int x4 = 200;
    int x5 = 95;
    int x6 = 175;
    int x7 = 205;

    int y1 = 40;
    int y2 = 150;
    int y3 = 50;
    int y4 = 200;
    int y5 = 250;
    int y6 = 95;
    int y7 = 75;
    int y8 = 205;
    int y9 = 225;


    for (int i = 0; i < kind; i++) {
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillOval( x3,330, 40,40 );      // Hoofd
        g.drawLine( x2,370, y2,380 );     // Nek
        g.fillRect( x1,380, 50,150 );    // Lichaam
        g.drawLine( x2,400, y4,470 );   // R Arm
        g.drawLine( x4,430, y5,470 );
        g.drawLine( x1,430, y1,490 );    // L Arm
        g.drawLine( x1,530, y6,620 );    // L Been
        g.drawLine( x5,620, y7,620 );
        g.drawLine( x6,530, y8,620 );   // R Been
        g.drawLine( x7,620, y9,620 );


        x1 = 100 + x1;
        x2 = x2 + 100;
        x3 = x3 + 100;
        x4 = x4 + 100;
        x5 = x5 + 100;
        x6 = x6 + 100;
        x7 = x7 + 100;

        y1 = 100 + y1;
        y2 = y2 + 100;
        y3 = y3 + 100;
        y4 = y4 + 100;
        y5 = y5 + 100;
        y6 = y6 + 100;
        y7 = y7 + 100;
        y8 = y8 + 100;
    }
    //afbeelding
    int tel;
    int xSS = 100;
    int ySS = 550;
    for (tel = 1; tel <= strandstoel; tel++) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        ImageIcon strandstoel = new 
ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/images/beach-chair.png"));
        g2d.drawImage(strandstoel.getImage(), xSS, ySS, null);
        xSS = xSS + 250;
        ySS = ySS + 0;
    }

    //RookPluim
    int teller;
    for (teller = 1; teller <= aantal; teller++) {
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);

    }

    // Versiering Vlieger
        if (null != vliegerKleur) {
            switch (vliegerKleur) {
                case "Rood":
                    g.setColor(Color.RED);
                    g.fillOval(120, 100, 10, 10);
                    g.fillOval(160, 95, 10, 10);
                    g.fillOval(200, 90, 10, 10);
                    g.fillOval(240, 85, 10, 10);
                    g.fillOval(280, 80, 10, 10);
                    g.fillOval(320, 70, 20, 20);
                    g.fillOval(320, 120, 10, 10);
                    g.fillOval(310, 160, 10, 10);
                    g.fillOval(305, 200, 10, 10);
                    g.fillOval(299, 240, 10, 10);
                    g.fillOval(294, 280, 10, 10);
                    break;
                case "Oranje":
                    g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
                    g.fillOval(120, 100, 10, 10);
                    g.fillOval(160, 95, 10, 10);
                    g.fillOval(200, 90, 10, 10);
                    g.fillOval(240, 85, 10, 10);
                    g.fillOval(280, 80, 10, 10);
                    g.fillOval(320, 70, 20, 20);
                    g.fillOval(320, 120, 10, 10);
                    g.fillOval(310, 160, 10, 10);
                    g.fillOval(305, 200, 10, 10);
                    g.fillOval(299, 240, 10, 10);
                    g.fillOval(294, 280, 10, 10);
                    break;
                case "Blauw": // Was normaal groen vlgs de opdracht, 
maar dit was niet zo goed zichtbaar
                    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                    g.fillOval(120, 100, 10, 10);
                    g.fillOval(160, 95, 10, 10);
                    g.fillOval(200, 90, 10, 10);
                    g.fillOval(240, 85, 10, 10);
                    g.fillOval(280, 80, 10, 10);
                    g.fillOval(320, 70, 20, 20);
                    g.fillOval(320, 120, 10, 10);
                    g.fillOval(310, 160, 10, 10);
                    g.fillOval(305, 200, 10, 10);
                    g.fillOval(299, 240, 10, 10);
                    g.fillOval(294, 280, 10, 10);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

    repaint();
}


private void jCheckBoxZonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent 
evt) {                                             
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    repaint();
}                                            

private void jSliderKinderenMouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent 
evt) {                                              
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    kind = this.jSliderKinderen.getValue();
    repaint();
}                                             

private void 
jTextFieldAantalStoelenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try{
    strandstoel = 
Integer.parseInt(this.jTextFieldAantalStoelen.getText());
    } catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Vul een getal in");
    }
    repaint();

}                                                       

private void jList1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    vliegerKleur = this.jList1.getSelectedValue();
    repaint();
}                                   

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
     try{
         aantal = Integer.parseInt(this.jTextFieldAantal.getText());
        breedte = Integer.parseInt(this.jTextFieldBreedte.getText());
        hoogte = Integer.parseInt(this.jTextFieldHoogte.getText());
     } catch(Exception e){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Vul een aantal + Hoogte en 
Breedte in");
     }

    repaint();
}                                        


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JCheckBox jCheckBoxZon;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
private javax.swing.JList<String> jList1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JSlider jSliderKinderen;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextFieldAantal;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextFieldAantalStoelen;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextFieldBreedte;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextFieldHoogte;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: I'm thinking you might need to override `getPreferredSize` and return a valid default size

Comment: The error is at line 322 of ProjectPanel, inside its initComponent() method. But you didn't post it.

Answer (score 1):

Also another possible cause for that error, which was the case for mine, is that you may unknowingly have added an element such as a `JLabel`, `JTextField`, etc. but it's very very tiny small that you are unable to recognize its presence thus while you compile it has an invalid smaller size.

To solve this, open your navigator and click on each element checking where it on the `JFrame` so that you can also see that tiny one.

I got it to work like that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that error is because sometimes when you create jFrame with textBox and Labels or another component and you forgot the identifier for example label